# Are there differentiable estimators for Entropy?

Tags: estimators, entropy, mutual-information, divergence

I have recently came across a paper on estimation of Information theoretic measure such as Entropy, Mutual Information and divergence, using a Mean Nearest Neighbor approach. Since, the estimator is differentiable, gradient based optimization could be used on it. [Paper Link](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3500-ica-based-on-a-smooth-estimation-of-the-differential-entropy)

I am trying to replicate the results of this paper with not much success. This also made me wonder, if there are other differentiable estimators of Entropy to be precise.

Comment: To me it makes more sense to try to estimate the density of probability, and then calculate an estimate based on it.